# Replacing ui router 0.2 with 1.0.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have upgraded ui-router v0.2 to 1.0.0 but I have some issues with my existing code. So I read in the official docs that

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'
```

is now replaced with `$transitions.onStart({},`

same with `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess'`  with `$transitions.onSuccess({},`

So far so good. But in my original code I have the following:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   // some code here
   $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
}
```

I tried the following:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function (toState, toParams) { 
     $state.go(toState, toParams);
}
```

But `toState` and `toParams` are not available ... I looked at the docs but cannot really figure out what should I do here. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the official 1.0 migration guide: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is located here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/feature-1.0/ You can setup specific callbacks for specific scenarios like this:

```
$transitionsProvider.onBefore({ to: 'my.state', from: '*' }, function(AsyncService) {
  return AsyncService.doSomeAsyncThing();
});
```