# Ui-router 1.0.0.beta1 $transitions.onSuccess from $rootScope.on('$stateSuccess',

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-components

In my AngularJS (v. 1.5.x), I'm converting my controller-based states to component-based states with [ui-router 1.0.0 (currently in beta 1)](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/).

I'm having troubles catching state changes, that where previously caught with `$rootScope.on('$stateSuccess', ...`. As far as I can tell, I am doing what described [in the docs](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html), and in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786841/replacing-ui-router-0-2-with-1-0-0), therefore I am wondering if I am missing something or if this is a bug of the beta 1 release.

I have not converted all controllers yet, only few.

The converted ones look like this (based on info gotten from [RFC: Routing to Angular 1.5 .component()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2627)):

```
.state('componentstate', {
    url: '/myUrl',
    component : 'myComponent'
});
```

Navigation to this states works fine.

To update my code to the new `Transitions` logic, I'm changing this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if($state.current.name == 'acontrollerbasedstate') // do stuff;
});
```

to this:

```
$transitions.onSuccess( { to: 'acontrollerbasedstate', from: '*' }, function() {
    // I've also tried { to: '*', from: '*' }
    console.log('running');
    // do stuff
});
```

Since it was not working, I've also testes all methods:

```
$transitions.onBefore( { to: '*', from: '*' }, function() {
  console.log('onBefore');
});
$transitions.onEnter( { to: '*', from: '*' }, function() {
  console.log('onEnter');
});
$transitions.onError( { to: '*', from: '*' }, function() {
  console.log('onError');
});
$transitions.onExit( { to: '*', from: '*' }, function() {
  console.log('onExit');
});
$transitions.onFinish( { to: '*', from: '*' }, function() {
  console.log('onFinish');
});
$transitions.onRetain( { to: '*', from: '*' }, function() {
  console.log('onRetain');
});
$transitions.onStart( { to: '*', from: '*' }, function() {
  console.log('onStart');
});
$transitions.onSuccess( { to: '*', from: '*' }, function() {
  console.log('onSuccess');
});
```

Unfortunately nothing ever gets printed in the console, which means the callback function of `$transitions.onSuccess` never gets executed.

```
//////
UPDATE
//////
```

I've tried without declaring `to` or `from`, and it works:

$transitions.onStart( {}, scrollToTop);

```
$transitions.onSuccess({}, function(){
    // here I use $scope.current.name, which for my purposes, works fine for now
});
```

Comment: show us your component controller

Comment: This looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267348/component-in-angularjs-1-5-doesnt-listen-broadcasted-event-from-scope

Comment: @gyc, I'm placing the `$transitions` calls in a directive, as I want to check for state changes from there. Why whould the code of the component matter?

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO, not sure actually, especially because there are no replies there so I did not get what the problem there is...

Comment: @ghego the transitions work on component routing. Why put the logic in a directive? How do you inject $transitions?

Comment: @gyc because I want to manipulate the DOM based on the state, and when the state changes I want to update the DOM. I've updated the question, it may be that it is a bug of ui-router.